# Accessing .model file in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, serialization, model, weka

I want to know how I can access the instances from the pretrained model created in Android Studio.

here is my sample code:

`Classifier mClassifier = weka.core.SerializationHelper.read(assetManager.open("iris_model_logistic_allfeatures.model"))`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [readAll](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/core/SerializationHelper.html#readAll-java.io.InputStream-) method, in order to return **model and dataset header** that the model was trained with. That method reads two objects, if possible, from the `java.io.ObjectInputStream` instance it generates for the supplied `java.io.InputStream` instance. The objects get returned as an Object array.

The [read](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/core/SerializationHelper.html#read-java.io.InputStream-) method only returns the model, i.e., the first object from the `java.io.ObjectInputStream`.